# Please help me in get height value of one instance of CGSize in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cgsize

I'm a newbie in XCode programming. I have following code:

```
CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0);

NSLog(@"[height] %@", firstSize.height);
//...
```

At runtime, I got the result:

```
height (null)
```

Could someone help me to explain while that code print null for firstSize.height?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%f` instead of `%@` :

```
CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0);
NSLog(@"[height] %f", firstSize.height);
```

`%@` is used for all objects, here you are dealing with Core its float type, you need to use `%f` for float.

If you want decimal precision as well, use `%.2f` for 2 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this nice function

```
 NSString * NSStringFromCGSize (
   CGSize size
);
```

defined by UIKit in UIGeometry.h (together with many other useful functions):

```
NSLog(@"Size: %@",NSStringFromCGSize(firstSize));
```